# Multithreading in UWP Windows 10

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-10, uwp

I am making an UWP app for Windows 10. I want to execute two methods in a separate thread other than the Parent/Default thread, so that my app can be a little faster. But I could not find Thread class in UWP. What I have is Task, but it's not simple as Thread.

The methods are like below.

```
public List<Rootobject> <Method_name>()
private List<string> <Method_name>()
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `Task` instead of `Thread` because `Thread` is not supported at the moment (see open ticket https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2576). What is not so easy by creating a `Task`?

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => {
              // Just loop.
              int ctr = 0;
              for (ctr = 0; ctr <= 1000000; ctr++)
              {}
              Console.WriteLine("Finished {0} loop iterations", ctr);
          } );
```

See the microsoft doc: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
Example with your methods:

```
// Running the method which returns List<string>
Task<List<string>> result = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExpensiveMethod());


public List<string> ExpensiveMethod()
{
    return ...;
}
```

Comment: I would not say obsolete but not supported at the moment see the open ticket: (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2576)

Answer (score 1):

We've developed an open source package for UWP (and .NET Standard in general) [which implements the `System.Threading.Thread` class](https://neosmart.net/blog/2017/system-threading-thread-universal-windows-platform-and-the-fragmentation-of-net-standard/) (and related objects such as exceptions and enums) using threads under the hood.

`TaskThreads` is freely available (MIT-licensed) [on GitHub](https://github.com/neosmart/TaskThreads) and [via NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskThread/), and should readily substitute as a drop-in replacement for the MS-provided (missing) STT class for UWP developers.